# Calculate Angular Position from a gyro

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, triangulation

I am working with a gyro that outputs Angular Velocity. I am wondering how I would calculate Angular Position from this data. I have read a couple different places that you need the (sample rate, previous rate, current rate) If this is all I need the sample rate (the time between measurments) is taken every `200ms`. Can someone give me an example of the formula and a solution? Lets say `Sample rate = 200ms; Previous rate= 20; Current rate= 50`. Thanks in advance math has never been a strong point for me.

Answer (score 1):

Plot  your angular velocity vs time. The angle at any time will be total area under your graph up to that time.

To get more help here you probably need to give more detail on what your various rates mean.

If you multiply your rate with the period of time in which it has been effective, and add up such contributions, then you get the current position.

Here is a guess (I am not familiar with your set up though)

so if in the first 200 ms your rate was 20 dps

and then in the next 200 ms your rate is 50 dps

then by the end of the second reading the angle has advanced by (noting 200 ms =0.2 sec)

.2*20 + .2*50= 4+10=14 degrees

But I am not sure why there are two rates previous and current. So use with caution!

Comment: The angular rates are measured in DPS(degrees per second)